# How does Node.JS handle duplicate transitive dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I apologize if my questions are naïve. In full disclosure I'm relatively new to Node.JS and JavaScript in general. I'm hoping someone could shed some light on how Node.JS handles duplicate, possibly transitive, dependencies? Not even in terms of the global namespace or any kind of conflicts, or different versions of the same module (e.g. v0.1 vs v0.2 elsewhere in your app), but more around being smart and efficient where possible. For example:

- Is there any chance that Node is smart enough in terms of footprint to not have multiple copies of the same exact version of the library in your modules folder? Something like 1 copy for each required version with symbolic links or something similar pointing to this code for each module that depends on that version of that module?
- What about in terms of loading duplicate modules into memory at runtime? If v0.1 of module x is already loaded into memory, if some other depended upon module comes along that requires that same version of that module, will the code be re-loaded into memory, or is Node smart enough to see that code is already loaded and re-use it? How sandboxed is Node in this regard?

Thanks!

Comment: generally, separate copies are used to avoid version conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js has no concept of versions.  The `require()` function resolves its argument to a full path to a `.js` file, and caches them by filename.

You may be asking how *npm* installs modules; that depends on the order in which you install them.

You can run `npm dedup` to do nice things here.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, then, that I can expect that my direct dependencies will each have their own paths to each module they transitively require, and that's the version that will be loaded? Am I understanding that dedupe will not help with this?

Comment: `npm dedup` will remove the duplicates, as long as the versions are compatible.  Whether they get created in the first place depends on the installation order.

Comment: Does this mean as "npm install" is doing its thing, if one of your dependencies has a nested dependency on something install has already run across, then any require statements for that module will then point to the one that's already been installed? And that dedupe then basically does the same thing if there are duplicates?

Comment: `npm install` will not install a module if a compatible version is already in the  search path.  See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Comment: It's making more sense to me. I'll keep reading and digesting. Thanks you've been helpful.